# MapBox/MapLibre - "text-field" : use of "text-field" requires a style "glyphs" property

Tags: javascript, mapbox, textfield, maplibre-gl

I have this problem when I try to put labels to my layers in Maplibre/mapbox.

`evented.ts:112 Error: layers.parcelles_ly.layout.text-field: use of "text-field" requires a style "glyphs" property`

Problem : my layer calls a style JSON, which has a glyphs property.

I tried with urls found like "https://demotiles.maplibre.org/font/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf" but this doesn't work.

This is the begin of my style JSON :

```
    "id": "cadastre",
    "crs": "EPSG:3857",
    "name": "Cadastre",
     "tiles": [
            "https://myurl/mydata/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
    ],
    "glyphs": "https://myurl/mydata/api/glyphs/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
    "layers": [... etc.
```

and how I call this style inside my JS Code:

```
            type: 'vector',
            url: 'app/js/json/style_cadastre.json'
          });
        
          map.addLayer({
            'id': 'parcelles_ly',
            "type": 'symbol',
            'source': 'parcelle',
            'source-layer': 'parcelles_label',
            
            'layout': {
              'text-field':['get', 'num_par'],
              'text-font': ['sarala']
            },
            'maxzoom': 24,
            'minzoom': 1
          });
```

I don't know why that doesn't work...

Thank you for your answers

Sylvain